# How to spell letters to google Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to get first name as input.

Eg: Audio input spelled out as **D O N A L D**

expected output: **DONALD**

Using Cloud Speech-to-Text (Google ASR), class Alpha Sequence.

The output is not consistent.

How to improve the model output accuracy, or any other method for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with lower case. it's work for me